# Proximity to a Shortest Path

Tags: metric-spaces

So I'm trying to find Proximity of a point $x$ to a Shortest Path between $a$ and $b$.

Things I *think* I know, given I have a metric $d(i,j)$ for the SP:

- There's no inner product (because there's no linearity in the first argument).

  - So I can't use projection onto the SP (even if I get a proportional proximity I can't project in the direction of the metric to get a point $p$ because the gradient vanishes at some points).
- Pythagorean Theorem holds for a metric.

$Proximity = d(x,p)$, where $p$ is the closest point to $x$ on the SP between $a$ and $b$

So:

$d(a,p)^2+d(x,p)^2=d(a,x)^2$

$d(b,p)^2+d(x,p)^2=d(b,x)^2$

$d(a,p)+d(b,p)=d(a,b)$

Then:

$\sqrt{d(a,x)^2-d(x,p)^2}+\sqrt{d(b,x)^2-d(x,p)^2}=d(a,b)$

Solve for $d(x,p)$:

$d(x,p) = \frac{\sqrt{d(a,x)^4+2 d(a,x)^2 (d(b,x)^2+d(a,b)^2)-(d(b,x)^2-d(a,b)^2)^2}}{2d(a,b)}$

Is this correct? The Pythagorean Theorem supposedly applies to metrics. But I have a hard time imagining orthogonal components for a metric where angles don't really make sense. On the other hand, even if angles don't make sense the properties you would find in a "right" angle are certainly there. If it's incorrect is there a way to get the proximity given the metric? Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: The Pythagorean theorem doesn't hold for general metrics. How could it? There is no notion of orthogonality in these spaces.

Comment: @Ian That seems like a bold statement but I think I know what you mean. I read that as long as the two sides of the triangle in the metric are independent to each other it holds irrespective of everything else (that statement may have been for a euclidean context though). So can we consider each as a separate term to get our result? It seems we can if you think about a SP metric. But I don't really know....I really don't.

Comment: No, that statement is definitely for the context of some inner product space.

Comment: @Ian If you stand by that statement, add it as an answer to the negative. (Even better if your response has a pointer in the right direction). I'll at least up-vote it for getting me to think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no counterpart of the Pythagorean theorem for a general metric space, or even for a general normed vector space. There is no way to really even define the statement, because there is no way to define orthogonality. Mere linear independence (in the normed vector space setting) is far from being sufficient. "Componentwise" independence (meaning that the componentwise product of the two vectors is the zero vector) is also not sufficient. You might get some intuition here by looking at the norms $\| x \|_p := \left ( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p \right )^{1/p}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, where $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ and $p \neq 2$. (For $p=\infty$ the previous formula does not make strict sense but it does as a limit.)

Comment: Lp was what got me to this point but thinking about it with a fresh head I see clearly that L1 violates. There's still a relation but it's not Pythagorean.